# How to securely serve client-side-only web content to mobile with convenience?

Tags: web-application, mobile, web-hosting

For a cryptocurrency client implementation, I am serving a single page webapp to mobile clients.  It is a client-side-only page.

I would like to serve this page to clients, but I fear tampering by hosts to change the code so that user passwords are intercepted.  The passwords, at least 128 bits of entropy enforced, are cryptocurrency signing key seeds.

Unfortunately, and this may be erroneous, it seems that mobile browsers cannot open and run local html files, or if they can, they cannot run css or js files.

I'm aware of apps that allow this, but I'd prefer that to be a last resort so to reach the least savvy.

Is the only option to physically manage a server myself to achieve the desired convenience?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you're worried about the host of the application tampering with it?  Presumably they also have access to all the data being stored for it...

Comment: @David I apologize for leaving out some key details!  It's a cryptocurrency client, and the passwords are brain wallet seeds.  Thank you for looking!

Comment: _I fear tampering by hosts to change the code so that user passwords are intercepted_ **who is the host? you said it is a client side app, so the host is the client? why should he bother to steal his own passwords?**

Comment: @aviv I am worried that the web host will alter the js, grab the password when it is entered, and send it via a websocket connection.

Comment: @Gracchus if you do not trust the web host, there is nothing you could do except of hosting the application yourself, But I am not sure that this is what you meant... do you actually think the hosting provider will alter your code?

Comment: @aviv It's for a cryptocurrency client.  The temptation is always there.

Answer (score 1):

Not understanding exactly what you are trying to defend against (see my comment above).

But in any way if you wish to serve html+css+js locally you could use Cordova to package your web app as a client app. Then you could also upload it to the market. (You can also use the OS's web browser controls to implement it yourself instead of using cordova)

Your other alternative is hosting your stuff on the web, probably utilizing PAAS as the preferred hosting option.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever there is a security issue - it is usually a design problem rather than an implementation problem.

You are worried that the clients will be able to steal other users' passwords by tampering - locally - with the application. This can only be possible if you are giving them free access to the passwords. How do they authenticate? How would they steal other users' passwords?

Because each user is local and they are concerned with their own local data, it should not be possible to tamper with the application to do anything malicious (If you have RESTful calls to a server, for example, just ensure there are some levels of server authentication. Only serve data to clients if the data is intended for clients and they will never be able to tamper with it.)

However, it sounds as if you do not currently operate any server back-end or authentication so I can only assume that any data generated has been done so by the user - and unless you're storing a file locally of all users/passwords (which doesn't seem feasible anyway!) , they will not have access to any other passwords or data.

Another way to think about this is that: if each client is isolated and does not connect to a server, is not authenticated (or loosely authenticated locally), then there is nothing to worry about because the clients can never gain access to the other clients.